# Struggling with `bundle install` - Could not delete previous installation (permission error)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll

Recently I spent hours to execute my blog made with minimal mistakes theme of Jekyll on local (Mac M1), and I always got stuck with `bundle install` step. I got the following error messages:

```
❯ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Resolving dependencies...
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.10
Using minitest 5.15.0
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using zeitwerk 2.5.4
Using public_suffix 4.0.7
Using bundler 2.4.4
Using coffee-script-source 1.11.1
Using execjs 2.8.1
Using faraday-em_synchrony 1.0.0
Using faraday-excon 1.1.0
Using faraday-httpclient 1.0.1
Using faraday-em_http 1.0.0
Using colorator 1.1.0
Using multipart-post 2.1.1
Using faraday-patron 1.0.0
Using faraday-net_http_persistent 1.2.0
Using faraday-net_http 1.0.1
Using faraday-retry 1.0.3
Using ruby2_keywords 0.0.5
Using forwardable-extended 2.6.0
Using rb-fsevent 0.11.1
Using faraday-rack 1.0.0
Using rexml 3.2.5
Using liquid 4.0.3
Using mercenary 0.3.6
Using safe_yaml 1.0.5
Installing gemoji 3.0.1
Installing racc 1.6.0 with native extensions
Using jekyll-paginate 1.1.0
Using rubyzip 2.3.2
Using jekyll-swiss 1.0.0
Using unicode-display_width 1.8.0
Using rainbow 3.1.1
Using webrick 1.7.0
Using i18n 0.9.5
Using addressable 2.8.0
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using tzinfo 1.2.9
Using pathutil 0.16.2
Using faraday-multipart 1.0.3
Using terminal-table 1.8.0
Using activesupport 6.0.4.8
Using jekyll-coffeescript 1.1.1
Using faraday 1.10.0
Using sawyer 0.8.2
Using octokit 4.22.0
Using jekyll-gist 1.5.0
Installing commonmarker 0.23.4 with native extensions
Installing http_parser.rb 0.8.0 with native extensions
Installing kramdown 2.3.2
Installing eventmachine 1.2.7 with native extensions
Installing unf_ext 0.0.8.1 with native extensions
Installing rouge 3.26.0
Installing ffi 1.15.5 with native extensions
Bundler::DirectoryRemovalError: Could not delete previous installation of `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/commonmarker-0.23.4`.
The underlying error was Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ apply2files - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/commonmarker-0.23.4/test/test_attributes.rb, with backtrace:
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2342:in `unlink'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2342:in `block in remove_file'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2347:in `platform_support'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2341:in `remove_file'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2330:in `remove'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:1470:in `block in remove_entry'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2389:in `block (2 levels) in postorder_traverse'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2389:in `block (2 levels) in postorder_traverse'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2393:in `postorder_traverse'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2388:in `block in postorder_traverse'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2387:in `each'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2387:in `postorder_traverse'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2388:in `block in postorder_traverse'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2387:in `each'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2387:in `postorder_traverse'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:1468:in `remove_entry'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:1383:in `remove_entry_secure'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler.rb:339:in `rm_rf'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:111:in `strict_rm_rf'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:19:in `install'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:200:in `install'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in `install'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in `install_from_spec'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:155:in `do_install'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:146:in `block in worker_pool'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/worker.rb:62:in `apply_func'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/worker.rb:57:in `block in process_queue'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `loop'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `process_queue'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/worker.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in create_threads'

Bundler Error Backtrace:
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:115:in `rescue in strict_rm_rf'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:110:in `strict_rm_rf'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:19:in `install'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:200:in `install'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in `install'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in `install_from_spec'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:155:in `do_install'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:146:in `block in worker_pool'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/worker.rb:62:in `apply_func'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/worker.rb:57:in `block in process_queue'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `loop'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `process_queue'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/worker.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in create_threads'

An error occurred while installing commonmarker (0.23.4), and Bundler cannot continue.

In Gemfile:
  github-pages was resolved to 226, which depends on
    jekyll-commonmark-ghpages was resolved to 0.2.0, which depends on
      jekyll-commonmark was resolved to 1.4.0, which depends on
        commonmarker


Bundler::DirectoryRemovalError: Could not delete previous installation of `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/gemoji-3.0.1`.
The underlying error was Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ apply2files - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/gemoji-3.0.1/bin/gemoji, with backtrace:
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2342:in `unlink'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2342:in `block in remove_file'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2347:in `platform_support'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2341:in `remove_file'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2330:in `remove'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:1470:in `block in remove_entry'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2389:in `block (2 levels) in postorder_traverse'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2389:in `block (2 levels) in postorder_traverse'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2393:in `postorder_traverse'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2388:in `block in postorder_traverse'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2387:in `each'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2387:in `postorder_traverse'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2388:in `block in postorder_traverse'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2387:in `each'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2387:in `postorder_traverse'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:1468:in `remove_entry'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:1383:in `remove_entry_secure'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler.rb:339:in `rm_rf'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:111:in `strict_rm_rf'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:19:in `install'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:200:in `install'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in `install'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in `install_from_spec'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:155:in `do_install'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:146:in `block in worker_pool'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/worker.rb:62:in `apply_func'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/worker.rb:57:in `block in process_queue'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `loop'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `process_queue'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/worker.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in create_threads'

Bundler Error Backtrace:
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:115:in `rescue in strict_rm_rf'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:110:in `strict_rm_rf'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:19:in `install'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:200:in `install'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in `install'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in `install_from_spec'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:155:in `do_install'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:146:in `block in worker_pool'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/worker.rb:62:in `apply_func'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/worker.rb:57:in `block in process_queue'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `loop'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `process_queue'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/worker.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in create_threads'

An error occurred while installing gemoji (3.0.1), and Bundler cannot continue.

In Gemfile:
  github-pages was resolved to 226, which depends on
    jemoji was resolved to 0.12.0, which depends on
      gemoji


Bundler::DirectoryRemovalError: Could not delete previous installation of `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/racc-1.6.0`.
The underlying error was Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ apply2files - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/racc-1.6.0/bin/racc, with backtrace:
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2342:in `unlink'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2342:in `block in remove_file'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2347:in `platform_support'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2341:in `remove_file'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2330:in `remove'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:1470:in `block in remove_entry'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2389:in `block (2 levels) in postorder_traverse'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2389:in `block (2 levels) in postorder_traverse'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2393:in `postorder_traverse'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2388:in `block in postorder_traverse'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2387:in `each'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2387:in `postorder_traverse'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2388:in `block in postorder_traverse'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2387:in `each'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:2387:in `postorder_traverse'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:1468:in `remove_entry'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:1383:in `remove_entry_secure'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler.rb:339:in `rm_rf'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:111:in `strict_rm_rf'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:19:in `install'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:200:in `install'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in `install'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in `install_from_spec'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:155:in `do_install'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:146:in `block in worker_pool'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/worker.rb:62:in `apply_func'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/worker.rb:57:in `block in process_queue'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `loop'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `process_queue'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/worker.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in create_threads'

Bundler Error Backtrace:
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:115:in `rescue in strict_rm_rf'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:110:in `strict_rm_rf'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:19:in `install'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:200:in `install'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in `install'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in `install_from_spec'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:155:in `do_install'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:146:in `block in worker_pool'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/worker.rb:62:in `apply_func'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/worker.rb:57:in `block in process_queue'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `loop'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `process_queue'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.4.4/lib/bundler/worker.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in create_threads'

An error occurred while installing racc (1.6.0), and Bundler cannot continue.

In Gemfile:
  github-pages was resolved to 226, which depends on
    jekyll-mentions was resolved to 1.6.0, which depends on
      html-pipeline was resolved to 2.14.1, which depends on
        nokogiri was resolved to 1.13.5, which depends on
          racc
```

I have no idea what should I do to successfully uninstall that previous version of `commonmarker`.
I've also tried `rbenv` as many posts suggest, which did not work at all.
If possible, is there any way to remove all gem files installed in the mysterious folder `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0` that I have no permission?

Here is a Gemfile that I'm using:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
# Hello! This is where you manage which Jekyll version is used to run.
# When you want to use a different version, change it below, save the
# file and run `bundle install`. Run Jekyll with `bundle exec`, like so:
#
#     bundle exec jekyll serve
#
# This will help ensure the proper Jekyll version is running.
# Happy Jekylling!
# This is the default theme for new Jekyll sites. You may change this to anything you like.
# gem "minimal-mistakes-jekyll"
# If you want to use GitHub Pages, remove the "gem "jekyll"" above and
# uncomment the line below. To upgrade, run `bundle update github-pages`.
gem "github-pages", "~> 226", group: :jekyll_plugins
gem "jekyll-include-cache", group: :jekyll_plugins
# If you have any plugins, put them here!
group :jekyll_plugins do
  gem "jekyll-feed", "~> 0.12"
end

# Windows and JRuby does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
# and associated library.
platforms :mingw, :x64_mingw, :mswin, :jruby do
  gem "tzinfo", "~> 1.2"
  gem "tzinfo-data"
end

# Performance-booster for watching directories on Windows
gem "wdm", "~> 0.1.1", :platforms => [:mingw, :x64_mingw, :mswin]

# Lock `http_parser.rb` gem to `v0.6.x` on JRuby builds since newer versions of the gem
# do not have a Java counterpart.
gem "http_parser.rb", "~> 0.6.0", :platforms => [:jruby]

gem "webrick", "~> 1.7"
gem "jekyll-spaceship"
```

Comment: I have the same problem , were you able to resolve it ?

Comment: @MAR In honest, I resolved but I forgot how I did exactly. But I remember that I followed the answer by anothermh below - there was an issue with using rbenv and I was using system ruby for installation. I just uninstalled rbenv and re-installed by *carefully* following the instructions, which eventually resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using system Ruby. [Don't use system Ruby](https://dontusesystemruby.com/).

You say this:

> I've also tried rbenv as many posts suggest, which did not work at all.

I can assure you that rbenv *does* work for many developers all across the world. I can also assure you that statements like **"did not work"** are absolutely meaningless and don't give any room for someone to attempt to help you. Please avoid using phrases like that when posting questions on StackOverflow. I say that because making rbenv work is your *actual* problem; getting system Ruby to work is *not* your problem because it's not what you should be doing.

I recommend that you:

1. [Uninstall rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#uninstalling-rbenv)
2. [Reinstall rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#installation) and *carefully follow every instruction to the letter*, especially when it comes to configuring your shell
3. Retry `bundle install`

If you prefer not to use rbenv then you can choose from:

1. [rvm](https://rvm.io/)
2. [asdf-vm](https://asdf-vm.com/guide/getting-started.html) and [asdf-ruby](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-ruby)
3. [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby#install)

All of which will also work very similarly to rbenv.

The bottom line is this: you have previously installed your gems using system Ruby and that is a very bad idea. There are many, many posts on StackOverflow where people are in the exact same position that you are in: they have attempted to use system Ruby and it has blown up in their face. There are **always** two options to resolve it:

1. Attempt to untangle the very specific cause of this very specific issue, which has details that are almost always hyper-specific and not shared by others encountering similar problems, thus making it extremely difficult to troubleshoot, causing it to take a very long time to resolve, and typically discouraging people from attempting to answer because the actual cause of these errors is buried somewhere deep in your shell history, requiring a lot of back-and-forth conversation to get you to dig out the relevant information to help resolve it (all through a website that discourages that very kind of back-and-forth conversation)
2. Don't use system Ruby and instead install Ruby yourself using widely accepted tools that have a large community of support, very clear and straightforward installation instructions, and common troubleshooting patterns

I strongly recommend that you choose the latter.